# Why do window.onload and window.addEventListener("load", function) respond differently?

Tags: javascript, html

I encountered this problem where they aren't responding the same way. Basically the html and css is (or you can directly move to javascript. I'll include html and css for the context).

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box green"></div>
    <div class="box red"></div>
    <div class="box blue"></div>
    <div class="box yellow"></div>
    <div class="box pink"></div>
    <div class="box orange"></div>
    <div class="box yellow"></div>
    <div class="box red"></div>
    <div class="box blue"></div>
    <div class="box pink"></div>
    <div class="box green"></div>
    <div class="box orange"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="score">"Your Score"</div>
</body>
```

This is the CSS

```
    body{
      height: 100vh;
      background: #00aaaa;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .container{
      background: rgba(0, 200, 200, .5);
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
      grid-gap: 5px;
    }
    .box:hover{
      border: 2.5px solid black;
    }
    .green{background: green;}
    .red{background: red;}
    .blue{background: blue;}
    .yellow{background: yellow;}
    .pink{background: pink;}
    .orange{background: orange;}
    .score{
      margin-top: 12px;
      width: 415px;
      text-align: center;
     }
```

The box shows it's color for 3 seconds after page loaded. And the becomes grey. The Javascript is such a way that whenever you click each box, it reveals it's color. Here is the javascript.

```
let $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
let $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

window.addEventListener("load", setTimeout(colorReset, 3000)); 

function colorReset(){
  $$(".box").forEach((boxColor)=>{
    boxColor.style.background = "grey";
  });
}

function revealColor(x){
  x.style.background = x.classList[1];
}

$$(".box").forEach((boxWithColor)=>{
  boxWithColor.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    revealColor(boxWithColor);
  });
});
```

Above script doesn't show the color of the box when clicked. But I replace window.addEvenListener("load", function) with window.onload = setTimeout("colorReset", 3000); Now it works. So, my question is do they respond differently?

Comment: `window.addEventListener("load", setTimeout(colorReset, 3000)); ` - this does not do what you think it does.

Comment: You are waiting 3 seconds after the window loads when you use setTimeout

Comment: @Dshiz Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. Also after 3 seconds, background of each box is set to grey. And then when I click the box, it shows it's respective color. That's what I'm trying to do. But when I click it doesn't it's respective color. It remains grey.

Comment: You also need to run the rest of the script (especially the `$$(".box").forEach((boxWithColor)=>{` part in a `DOMContentLoaded` handler rather than in the root script body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two main things wrong with your script as-is:

1. You are using `setTimeout` incorrectly with `addEventListener`.
2. You are evaluating `$$(".box")` before the HTML has been fully loaded, so `document.querySelectorAll` will return empty or incomplete results.

---

### Part 1: `addEventListener` with `setTimeout`:

Your code needs to pass a **function-reference** into `addEventListener`, but your code is actually passing a `number` value because you're invoking `setTimeout` at the call-site rather than passing a reference to `setTimeout` (which wont work anyway, as `addEventListener` needs the callback function to have a single `Event` parameter, and the `number` value originates from `setTimeout` which returns a "timer-id" you can pass to `clearTimeout` to cancel an active timer).

Change this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", setTimeout(colorReset, 3000));
```

to this:

```
// ES3-style:
window.addEventListener("load", function( e ) { setTimeout(colorReset, 3000); } );

// ES5-style (arrow-function, lambda-function):
window.addEventListener("load", e => setTimeout(colorReset, 3000) );
```

---

Also, you should avoid using the old-style (very, very-old-style) `onload`/`onclick`/etc-style event properties because they don't support multiple-dispatch (at least not without some gnarly hacks).

### Part 2: Only traverse the DOM *after* it's loaded.

- I assume your HTML page has your script in an inline `<script>` element (not using `<script src="">` which is located in the `<head>`.

  - This means the browser will run `$$(".box").forEach((boxWithColor)=>{` when it immediately encounters the script.
  - This won't work because when the above selector is evaluated *there are no `div.box` elements loaded into the DOM yet!

To fix this move your entire script into a separate `function` and pass that into `addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded' )`. Also consider using `for-of` instead of `NodeList.forEach`, and moving the `setTimeout` call into the function too, like so:

```
const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
const $  = document.querySelector.bind(document);

function onDOMLoaded( e ) {
    
    for( const box of $$('.box') ) {
        
        boxWithColor.addEventListener( 'click', ce => revealColor( ce.currentTarget ) );
    }

    setTimeout( colorReset, 3000 );
}
    
window.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", onDOMLoaded ); 

function colorReset() {
  $$(".box").forEach((boxColor)=>{
    boxColor.style.background = "grey";
  });
}

function revealColor(x){
  x.style.background = x.classList[1];
}
```

Comment: still didn't work. Now the background doesn't even change to grey. At first it changed all of  it's color to grey after showing the color for each box for 3 seconds.

Comment: @LForLaddu I suspect something else is going on. Please update your question post to include **all** of your code as an interactive snippet or JSFiddle.

Comment: @LForLaddu I found the other issue and I've updated my answer.